# How can I glide longer?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I want to glide longer but I don't know if I need the grappel accelerator and where I can get it? Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the Accelerator from the very beginning, although you won't be able to use it until you leave Blackgate Prison.

The Grapple Accelerator works in exactly the same way as in Arkham City. Grapple to a ledge and double-tap **X** (PS3)/ **A** (Xbox 360)/ <kbd>Space</kbd> (PC) while your grapple is still pulling. It only works if you're pulling from a certain distance.

Comment: if no grapple anchor is near then diving for a bit using the shoulder buttons, RT on Xbox, then holding down on the left stick will make batman glide further.

Comment: How you go about unlocking it in `Arkham Origins` vs `Arkham City` is indeed different.  In `Arkham Origins` its simply unlocked and through the normal course of the guide your introduced to it.  In `Arkham City` it was actually an `unlocked` gadget enchancement.  Basically you unlocked the ability within 20 minutes of playing the game considering the intial time within `Blackgate Prison` is basically a tutorial on the `Free Flow Fighting System`

Answer (score 1):

Too glide longer, just simply dive bomb and glide upwards over and over again. To grapnel accelerate just simply grapple onto a ledge and double tap A(X-Box), X(PlayStation), or space for computers.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to glide longer is to alternate diving and gliding gently upwards. You can usually get almost back to the height before the dive on each cycle which allows you to go pretty far. Of course the accelerator is also helpful and as already noted is available from the start but is not necessary for long glides (such as those required by the achievement type things).